# how to nested value_counts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

hello friends i'm very confused with nested value_counts in pandas

i have example dataframes:

```
SenderID        Status        long
john            1              2
john            0              1
eddie           1              1
eddie           1              2
eddie           1              2
eddie           0              1
```

and i want the output like this:

```
Sender ID       Status         long      sum
John            0               1        1
                                2        0  
                1               1        0
                                2        1
eddie           0               1        1
                                2        0
                1               1        1
                                2        2
```

anyone know it? thankyou, i use pd.series.value_counts but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for aggregate count and then add missing categories by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) of [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['SenderID','Status','long']).size()
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)

df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  SenderID  Status  long  count
0    eddie       0     1      1
1    eddie       0     2      0
2    eddie       1     1      1
3    eddie       1     2      2
4     john       0     1      1
5     john       0     2      0
6     john       1     1      0
7     john       1     2      1
```